# AppleScript to Outlook: Format Text Color in New Message?

Tags: outlook, applescript

I have an AppleScript that creates a new (HTML-formatted) email in Outlook. I have everything working the way I want but I can't seem to change the color of some of the text within the **body** of the email. Can this be done via AppleScript?

Thank you in advance,
Jon :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a body with some red text that can be included in your email creation Applescript:

```
set theContent to ("Hi:" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Second <span style=" & "color:red;" & ">word</span> is red." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Bye," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Buddy")
```